# Largest Palindrome product (Project Euler) -- C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve the [problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) of Project Euler with C++.

*A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.*

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int num1){
    int num2, digit, rev = 0;
    num1 = 0;

     num2 = num1;
     do
     {
        digit = num1 % 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + digit;
        num1 = num1 / 10;
     } while (num1 != 0);

     if (num2 == rev){
         return true;
     }
     else{
         return false;
     }
};

int main(){

    int product = 1321;
    int num1 = 999;
    int num2 = 999;
    while(isPalindrome(product)!=1){
        product= num1*num2;
        if(isPalindrome(product)==1){
            cout<< product;
            break;
        }
    num1--;
    };
};
```

I took product = 1321 as an arbitrary value so as to substitute the garbage value stored initially. However, when I run this code, I do not get any output in my console. It is totally blank as if the "if" condition is not being executed. I have tried the same code with smaller numbers, but it still doesn't work. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be only checking the numbers formed by a reducing `num1` and a *constantly-set-to-999* `num2`.

I suspect you're seeing no output because no number `999n, 0 < n < 1000` is palindromic.

I *could* be wrong but, in any case, you need to check *other* value of `num2` anyway.

Something like this (pseudo-code) would be a good start:

```
bigPalin = -1
for n1 in 100..999: # Three-digits means 100 thru 999.
    for n2 in 100..999:
        prod = n1 * n2
        if prod > bigPalin:
            if isPalindrome(prod):
                bigPalin = prod
if bigPamin != -1:
    print bigPalin
```

By the way, the check for a number being greater than the current largest palindrome is done *first* since a single multiplication is almost certainly a cheaper operation that a palindrome check.

---

For completion (and I suggest you *don't* use this until you've given it a good attempt on your own), this is the C code I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int isPalin(int num) {
    // Use temporary to create reversed value.

    int test = num, rev = 0;
    while (test > 0) {
        rev = rev * 10 + (test % 10);
        test /= 10;
    }

    // Return check that original and reversed are same.

    return rev == num;
}

int main() {
    // Largest palindrome and factors that made it.

    int bigPalin = -1, big1 = 0, big2 = 0;

    // Loop through values for n1.

    for (int n1 = 100; n1 < 1000; ++n1) {
        // Addition probably faster than multiplication, so use that,
        // adding n1 each time rather than working out n1 * n2.
        // Also we baseline at 99*n1 so first is 100*n1.

        int prod = 99 * n1;
        for (int n2 = 100; n2 < 1000; ++n2) {
            prod += n1;

            // Don't check for palindrome if product is not greater,
            // this works because C shortcuts logical AND.

            if (prod > bigPalin && isPalin(prod)) {
                // A bigger palindrome? Store details.

                big1 = n1;
                big2 = n2;
                bigPalin = prod;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print out final details.

    printf("%d x %d = %d\n", big1, big2, bigPalin);
    return 0;
}
```

Running that under Ubuntu with timing shows that it's pretty quick, clocking in just under four-hundredths of a second):

```
pax@paxBox1> time ./myTestProg
913 x 993 = 906609

real    0m0.038s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: I see your point. I'll try reducing num2 as well and see if that works.